# Altering MSSQL table protected by RLS (SSDT)

Tags: sql-server, database, deployment, sql-server-data-tools, row-level-security

When adding a new column to a table protected by Row Level Security in MSSQL 2016, I get the following error when trying to publish the database using SQL Server Data Tools:

> The current operation will cause data motion on table X. Data motion can not be performed on this table because it has row level security enabled by policy Y. To allow this operation use SqlPackage.exe with option /p:AllowUnsafeRowLevelSecurityDataMovement

I suspect that it wants to recreate the table, which might result in data loss if the deployment user is not granted access to data by the RLS predicates. However I am unable to find any documentation about this.

More importantly, what is best practice for handling such deployment scenario ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 aspects to this scenario:

- Why is the addition of a column causing a data motion operation to occur?
- What is the danger introduced by Row Level Security?

**Minimizing / avoiding data motion**

In general adding a new column should not require data motion. If added to the end of a table definition this can be done via an ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN operation, and SSDT is smart enough to do this for you. However if added in the middle of a table the default behavior is to do a full data motion which can be very costly on large tables. To avoid this:

- Always try to add columns to the end where possible.
- If this is not possible, recent versions of SSDT & SqlPackage have an `IgnoreColumnOrder` flag that will treat column additions in the middle of the table as if they were added to the end. This can cause some complications (e.g. schema compare must have this set too or it'll show differences between the source project & database version of the table), but is usually worth it to avoid unnecessary data motion during deployment

**Handling Row Level Security (RLS) + Data Motion**

If you do really need to make a change that causes data motion, the risk with RLS is that your user doesn't have access to all rows in a table. Since data motion copies data to a temp table, then drops the original & does a rename, you would lose any rows that your user could not see.

The solution is to set the `/p:AllowUnsafeRowLevelSecurityDataMovement` flag, but to verify that your user is not part of any row level filtering scheme. A good practice is to only apply those schemes to users with limited permissions (e.g your app roles), while using a role with greater permissions when deploying (an admin role). If you do this you're safe to deploy, but the flag is there to at least warn about this / avoid accidental data loss.

Comment: So do I understand it correctly, that using IgnoreColumnOrder the added column would be added to the end, even though the database project defines otherwise ? Usually I tend to add columns in the order where it makes more sense when skimming through table data. But maybe one should use views for that if a specific order is desired ?

Comment: Are you also saying that one should build in a rule in the security predicate, to allow all rows visible for certain "admin" SQL-users ? That would also solve the issue of seemingly empty tables when viewing data through management studio. In the current project, a user-id is set on the session context, and used to determine the right of individual application users (not sql users). To view data in management studio one has to set the appropriate user id on the context, which obviously is quite cumbersome.

Comment: Regarding column order: you're right that you should use views for logical "makes sense" ordering. Tables cannot have columns added in the middle. They're either added to the end, or you create a whole new table. And yes, ignore column order means they're put at the end even though it doesn't look that way in the project

Comment: Regarding security predicates: what I'm saying is that there's a risk if the user you use to deploy doesn't have permissions to view data in all tables. Whatever your scheme, it should defend against this risk or data motion will cause data loss. Hence the block in our code.

Comment: Makes sense. Is it good practice to have a special rule to allow the deployment user to see all data - and also having a user that one can use in management studio to view all data ? As it is in the current implementation, the rights are based solely on an ASP.NET user id being set on the session context by a variable. Meaning that both using management studio, and deploying, one needs to set a user with the right data access in order to do data manipulation.

Comment: I can't speak to the deep details / best practices of the feature. Just what's required to succeed in actually deploying it. I hope I've answered your SSDT-specific questions!

Comment: You certainly did. Thanks.

Comment: I was searching for the error SQL71616: SR0104 and it brought me here, I'm not sure how, but the error I have is very similar, but with a different feature: Stretch database. The package identified my database is stretched and created an error due to a default.

I already have a deployment contributor filter which would have removed the default from the script, but the error happened first. Is there an option for this?